# Element-wise shifting from smaller array to a larger array

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, arduino-c++

I am programming an ESP32 in the Arduino framework. For my application, I need to create a buffer which will store information from both the present and the last time it was accessed. Here is what I am attempting to do.

```
//first buffer
char buffer1[4];

//second buffer
char buffer2[8];

void setup {
    //setup
}

//buffer1 values will change with each iteration of loop from external inputs
//buffer2 must store most recent values of buffer1 plus values of buffer1 from when loop last ran

for example:

**loop first iteration**
void loop {
    buffer1[0] = {1};
    buffer1[1] = {2};
    buffer1[2] = {3};
    buffer1[3] = {1};

    saveold(); //this is the function I'm trying to implement to save values to buffer2 in an element-wise way
}
//value of buffer2 should now be: buffer2 = {1,2,3,1,0,0,0,0}

**loop second iteration**
void loop {
    buffer1[0] = {2};
    buffer1[1] = {3};
    buffer1[2] = {4};
    buffer1[3] = {2};

    saveold();
}

//value of buffer2 should now be: buffer2 = {2,3,4,2,1,2,3,1}
```

From what I've been able to understand through searching online, the "saveold" function I'm trying to make 
should implement some form of memmove for these array operations

I've tried to piece it together, but I always overwrite the value of buffer2 instead of somehow shifting new values in, while retaining the old ones

This is all I've got:

```
void saveold() {
  memmove(&buffer2[0], &buffer1[0], (sizeof(buffer1[0]) * 4));
}
```

From my understanding, this copies buffer1 starting from index position 0 to buffer2, starting at index position 0, for 4 bytes (where 1 char = 1 byte).

Computer science is not my backround, so perhaps there is some fundamental solution or strategy that I am missing. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You are not really moving anything. You are just copying from `buffer1` to the same location in `buffer2` every time. I personally wouldn't bother moving actual data but instead just keep a flag which tells you what byte to start copying to on each call. But if you really must copy then do: `memmove(&buffer2[4], &buffer2[0], (sizeof(buffer2[0]) * 4)); memcpy(&buffer2[0], &buffer1[0], (sizeof(buffer1[0]) * 4));`

Comment: Pick C or C++, not both.  The best answers are language  dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple options to implement `saveold()`:

**Solution 1**

```
void saveold() {
    // "shift" lower half into upper half, saving recent values (actually it's a copy)
    buffer2[4] = buffer2[0];
    buffer2[5] = buffer2[1];
    buffer2[6] = buffer2[2];
    buffer2[7] = buffer2[3];
    // copy current values
    buffer2[0] = buffer[0];
    buffer2[1] = buffer[1];
    buffer2[2] = buffer[2];
    buffer2[3] = buffer[3];
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
void saveold() {
    // "shift" lower half into upper half, saving recent values (actually it's a copy)
    memcpy(buffer2 + 4, buffer2 + 0, 4 * sizeof buffer2[0]);
    // copy current values
    memcpy(buffer2 + 0, buffer1, 4 * sizeof buffer1[0]);
}
```

**Some notes**

- There are even more ways to do it. Anyway, choose the one you understand best.
- Be sure that `buffer2` is exactly double size of `buffer1`.
- `memcpy()` can be used safely if source and destination don't overlap. `memmove()` checks for overlaps and reacts accordingly.
- `&buffer1[0]` is the same as `buffer1 + 0`. Feel free to use the expression you better understand.
- `sizeof` is an operator, not a function. So `sizeof buffer[0]` evaluates to the size of `buffer[0]`. A common and most accepted expression to calculate the size of an array dimension is `sizeof buffer1 / sizeof buffer1[0]`. You only *need* parentheses if you evaluate the size of a data type, like `sizeof (int)`.

**Solution 3**

The last note leads directly to this improvement of solution 1:

```
void saveold() {
    // "shift" lower half into upper half, saving recent values
    size_t size = sizeof buffer2 / sizeof buffer2[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i) {
        buffer2[size / 2 + i] = buffer2[i];
    }
    // copy current values
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i) {
        buffer2[i] = buffer1[i];
    }
}
```

To apply this knowledge to solution 2 is left as an exercise for you. ;-)

Comment: Using memcpy on a microcontroller is almost never the correct solution. In some 95% of the cases where people use memcpy in such systems, they should be using pointer swaps instead. Though in this specific case, the best solution seems to be keeping a single ring buffer - assuming there aren't hardware restrictions such as DMA enforcing a double-buffer design, which nothing in the question indicates.

Comment: @Lundin If you need performance and have enough RAM, that's right. The other way around `memcpy()` is OK. As I wrote, there are more possibilities, and it all depends on the requirements and environment. I just picked up the OP where he is.

Comment: The OP's code as-is already got multiple buffers, so with minimal changes, the correct solution is to do pointer swaps.

Comment: Honestly, the pure simplicity of Solution 1 is very appealing. It also worked very well for my application, so I'm going to stick with it. However, I will try to implement a ring buffer as well (now that I know what it is called), for learning purposes. This has been educational!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use buffer pointers, ***not*** by doing hard-copy backups. Doing hardcopies with memcpy is particularly bad on slow legacy microcontrollers such as AVR. Not quite sure what MCU this ESP32 got, seems to be some oddball one from Tensilica. Anyway, this answer applies universally for any processor where you have more data than CPU data word length.

> perhaps there is some fundamental solution or strategy that I am missing.

Indeed - it really sounds that what you are looking for is a *ring buffer*. That is, an array of fixed size which has a pointer to the beginning of the valid data, and another pointer at the end of the data. You move the pointers, not the data. This is much more efficient both in terms of execution speed and RAM usage, compared to making naive hardcopies with `memcpy`.